# vim and notepad++

Tags: vim, notepad++

So a lot of my programmer buddies have urged me to switch from (g)vim to a "real" text editor like notepad++.  My opinion has always been that they simply don't understand how to use vim.  Lately, I've been hearing more and more people talking about notepad++ and I got to wondering...  Does notepad++ actually have any features that Vim doesn't or vice versa?  Nobody has actually been able to give me any legitimate reason to make the switch other than that they like it more.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: This is controversial and a matter of taste. However to suggest vim is not a "real" editor is downright ludicrous.

Comment: Belongs on Programmers, instead of here.

Comment: This particular kind of question has been covered on Programmers SE several times, migrating it there wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: I don't quite see how a comparison of features is a matter of taste or controversial.  I suppose I'll just look elsewhere for the answer.  What exactly is "Programmers SE"?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Tool are tools. Use whatever tool will get your task done. If vim makes you productive, then go ahead.

Comment: Well, this was closed as a non-constructive question but has 3 good answers with good points, plus more that 26000 views. I wonder what a real constructive question is then?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Vim has modal editing (answering the vice versa part). And it runs in a terminal. You are likely correct; if "vim" isn't a real text editor, I'm not sure what is. I guess `ed`, the standard Unix text editor, would be the only real one.

Answer (score 23):

Don't let the peer pressure get to you. They're just jealous because they can't delete a line with two keystrokes.

Vim is just as much of a text editor as Notepad++. You can mod vim to have colors, tabs, basically everything that Notepad++ has and so much more.

Comment: To be fair, they actually can: CTRL+L in Notepad++.

Comment: I guess it's even there in vim because you have to esc to get into command mode, and then d+d to delete a line. Good point!

Answer (score 17):

Vim is about touch typist shortcuts. Notepad++ is a usual text editor. I have been using vim for years now and I would not trade it for Notepad++. However, to a new user its definitively easier to use Notepad++ than vim. Vim has a very bad learning curve.

Comment: Ehhh, vim is also a "text editor with coloration" too, though.

Comment: @DanielDiPaolo yes you are right. I edited my post to remove confusion. Most text editors today have so much features, lets keep it the most fundamental difference.

Comment: although notepadd++ would be easier to "learn",  it took me two full weeks to learn my way around vim... the whole "bad learning curve" argument is pure crap.

Comment: @Begui two weeks to learn how to use a text editor seems like a bad learning curve to me. Its only a question of relativity.

Comment: Psychologically, most developers, once they figure out how to be productive in VIM after a lot of hard graft because it does have a high learning curve. They sub-consciously tout it as being better than any other editor.

I am a great follower of the maxim "Don't Make Me Think". In that respect, Notepad++ scores better.

Comment: @Begui I know this is an old post, but 2 weeks is enough only to learn the very thin surface. The documentation of VIM is 3800 pages. Probably you got to know this in the last decade :)

Comment: Any software can have it's complexities.... 10 years after posting this, I still use it every day.... Do I know or use every feature.. nope.. but you can become very comfortable and come up with a flow quickly... Too complex for you? fine.... use notepad...